# Composition of two inner products

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$ and that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are inner products on the subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$. Show that there is unique inner product $f$ on $V$ s.t.

1. $W_2 = W_1^{\perp}$.
2. $f(\alpha, \beta) = f_k(\alpha, \beta)$, when $\alpha, \beta$ are in $W_k$ where $k = 1, 2$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $v,w\in V$ and try to calculate $f(v,w)$ using $V=W_1\oplus W_2$, the two given conditions and the properties of inner products.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  If you write vectors in $W_1 \oplus W_2$ as pairs $(w_1, w_2)$ then show that $f((a, b), (c, d)) = f_1(a, c) + f_2(b, d)$ works.

Comment: How to show the uniqueness? I have worked out as you have suggested.

Comment: Assume you have another inner product $g$ that satisfies conditions $1$ and $2$.  Use these two properties to show that $g((a, b), (c, d)) = f((a, b), (c, d))$.  Remember that $(a, b) = (a, 0) + (0, b)$.

Comment: Please expand this part a little.